# How to translate "He can't buy me" in French?

Tags: pronoms-personnels

I was studying les pronoms personnels and it's written in my textbook that:

*Indirect object pronouns are:*

> *Lui, leur, me, se, nous, vous*

— Which is kind of confusing because it doesn't include the "y"—

*Meanwhile, direct object pronouns are:*

> *Le, la, les*

In the direct objects pronouns there's no mention of (me, te, vous, nous) so if I want to say a sentence like:

> He bought you/ me/ us

How should I construct this sentence? Should I use moi/ toi/ vous instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many pronouns and it can definitely be confusing. Here are the categories you're talking about:

- pronoms personnels sujets: je, tu, il/elle/on, nous, vous, ils/elles
- pronoms compléments directs: me, te, le/la, nous, vous, les
- pronoms compléments indirects: me, te, lui, nous, vous, leur
- pronoms *y* et *en* (other situations)
- pronoms toniques: moi, toi, lui/elle, nous, vous, eux/elles

So to translate *He bought you/ me/ us*, you can say: *Il t'/m'/nous a acheté-e-s* -> don't forget to adjust the participe passé with the COD!

To know more about these different categories in grammar, here is an article for you: https://sweet-french-learning.com/glossaire-grammatical/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what your book actually says but *me/te/nous/vous* can be used as both direct and indirect object pronouns.

Your sentence translates then to:

> *Il ne peut pas m'acheter.*

Same for:

> *Il m'a acheté, il t'a acheté, il nous a acheté*